# What is the Difference between Shaiva and Shakta?

Tags: shaivism, sects, shaktism

Both sects believe in the oneness of Shiva - Shakti as the supreme essence of the vishvam.

So what is the difference between the two?

Can I have a compare and contrast type answer?
Like in what ways they are similar and in what ways they differ?

For example, as far as i understand, both consider the Shiva Shakti as a couple as the highest.

Also, I understand that there are multiple denominations within each of these two sects. So i expect a generalised answer only if it's not too much to ask.

**I am editing the question for focused enhancement**

Since mod team asked to edit question to make it focused.

I would like to request it to how Shaktism and Shaivism differ in terms of their soteriology and the relationship between Shiva and Shakti in the two sects.

It would be really helpful if any excerpt from a renowned practitioner of either sect can be quoted, who might have explained basic differences.

Comment: I think this is too broad (Needs more focus) and also definition of Shaiva and Shakta can be subjective too. Maybe you can limit your question to something specific.

Comment: antaH shAktaH bahiH shaivaH vyavahAre tu vaiShNavaH...

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto this verse is good..where is this verse taken from?

Comment: @TheDestroyer either from Kaularnava or pks

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It's from some Smartha text and used for Adi Shankaracharya....

Comment: @vidya No. It's from PKS. And PKS, you won't find original version anywhere. So can't help in validation.

Answer (score 1):

Although both groups consider *Śiva* & *Śakti* to be on equal footing, there are certain theological differences.

1. *Śākta*s believe that *Ādyāśākti* is the lone progenitor of everything, including *Sadāśiva*. *Śaiva*s disagree, for they reject the notion of *Sadāśiva* being caused to manifest by any other entity. Instead, they believe that everything, including *Ādyāśakti* is created by *Sadāśiva*.
2. In the *Saundaryalaharī*, *Ādi Śaṅkara* makes the following play of words - without the 'i'-kāra (which is used to denote feminine gender in grammer), *Śiva* (Ever-Auspicious) becomes *śava* (corpse, the most inauspicious object). *Śākta*s interpret this to mean that the existence of *Sadāśiva* is dependent on the independent *Ādyāśakti*.  *Śaiva*s disagree, they believe that *Sadāśiva* is independent, rather it is *Ādyāśakti* whose manifestation is dependent upon *Sadāśiva*. They interpret this line to mean that in the absence of *Ādyāśakti*, the cosmos ceases to exist & *Sadāśiva* becomes unresponsive like a corpse (as anybody who can elicit a response ceases to exist).
3. *Sāṁkhya* philosophy states that the cosmos manifests due to interaction of the static *Puruṣa* with the ever-changing *Prakṛti*. *Śaiva*s interpret *Puruṣa* as *Sadāśiva* & *Prakṛti* as *Ādyāsakti*, by comparing *Puruṣa* with *Paramātman* of *Vedānta* & *Prakṛti* with *māyā*, *Sadāśiva* stands superior to *Ādyāśakti*. Meanwhile *Sākta*s state that *Ādyāsakti* Herself is the unmanifested *Brahman* who at the time of creation becomes both *Puruṣa* & *Prakṛti* by the action of Her own indescribable *māyā* & it is only for the sake of clarification at the dualist level, *Puruṣa* is referred to as a separate entity by the name of *Sadāśiva*.
4. *Śaiva*s believe that nothing exists above *Śivaloka* & that *Śakta*s ultimately reach the abode of *Pārvatī*, which lies below it. *Śakta*s believe that *Śivaoka* lies below *Ādyāśākti*'s abode.
5. *Śaiva*s consider the 28 *Śaivāgama*s as their authority  while *Sākta*s derive authority from their own set of *Āgama*s & *Nigama*s.
6. *Śaiva*s & *Śakta*s have their own unique codes of conducting *Tāntrika* worship.
7. *Śaiva*s emphasize on the identification of *paśu*, *pāśa* & *Paśupati*, while *Sākta*s emphasize on arousal of the *kuṇḍalinī* upto the level of *sahasrāra*.
8. Although both are heavily ritual oriented, *Śaiva*s (especially *Viraśaiva*s & *Śaivasiddhāntin*s) *tāntrika*s emphasize a bit more on devotion compared to *Sākta* *tāntrika*s. *Sakta*s heavily emphasize on *japa* & *puraścaraṇa*.

Much of the above mentioned *siddhānta*s have been derived from the *Śivapurāṇa*, the *Devībhāgavatapurāṇa* & a few *Tāntrika* compendiums.

Comment: Point 4,5,6,7 and 8.. can you add supporting verses for the same?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Refer to Shivapurāṇa, Devībhāgavatapurāṇa, Mahābhāgavata Upapurāṇa, Kriyākramodyotika of Aghoraśivacārya & Mantramahodadhi of Mahīdhara Bhaṭṭa.

Comment: @অনু Do you know the meaning of "Supportive verses " ?